# Trying to find a way to control background color via 11 different buttons. Question about template strings?

Tags: javascript, template-strings

I have 11 buttons with their own class, as well as all 11 share the class .theme-color. I am trying to have it change to the background color on the button class. My idea was to get the class into the function and add a . to the beginning, then use the style.background to it to get the value in css.

```
let allThemes = document.querySelectorAll('.theme-color');
allThemes.forEach(theme => theme.addEventListener('click', themeState()));
function themeState() {
  return function (event) {
    let classFilter = event.target.classList[1];
    console.log(classFilter);
    let helpDocument = document.querySelector(`.${classFilter}`);
    console.log(helpDocument);
  };
}
```

Something tells me I can't do this but honestly I cannot figure out any other way. Each class has a (class).style.background = undefined even though it has it set in CSS.

Help please.

Comment: "Something tells me I can't do this" - why? Does it work if you try it, and if not do you get errors?

Comment: because the value is null

Comment: Why does `themeState` need to be a function? Also please confirm what `classFilter` is

Comment: because it has to go through a process of being clicked, finding which button, finding that buttons class, finding the class.style.background, and then changing it. Trying not to type repetitive code like 11 event listeners. That did work though lol.

Comment: Fair enough. The simple example made it seem unnecessary. Still, `classList[1]` is likely undefined. Consider debugging to find out why? (We can't see we cannot see the HTML)

Comment: https://codepen.io/jverdugt/pen/dyzEPNp  if it helps to see the entire code

Comment: It kinda does, but it's not really fair to ask strangers to debug an entire program. The example doesn't show the issue you're facing. May you update the example to be a [mcve]?